# rss2json with Medium feed doesn't always work. "probably not a valid RSS feed"

Tags: rss, medium.com-publishing-api

I use rss2json.com for my Medium posts.

https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@username
works fine, but sometimes the response is

> Feed could not be converted, probably not a valid RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

got same problem for my website. It used to work perfectly fine until 2 or 3 days, everything broke. I couldn't use the rss2 to fetch them anymore. I had to use a lambda on aws to get the feed there, parse it and send it as response. It seems aswell some property have changed, and the thumbnail/pubDate properties are gone as well. Im surprise not more people are reporting this issue.

The only thing to do is set up your own fetch/parsing from a server or a quick workaround that i found, but not spotless is to use this:

```
https://www.convertjson.com/cgi-bin/url-to-json.php?callback=loadDataAndRun&url=yourMediumFeedUrl
```

It's a UI online service that allow you to parse from an URL,not sure if they allow this usage, but i had to find a quick solution to fix it until i set up my own server to do this job.

Comment: I had this issue again one month before and after ~ a week again the same problem.
No response from rss2 contact form

"Im surprise not more people are reporting this issue."
Exactly 

Alternative but without categories and I think thumbnail is:
https://www.toptal.com/developers/feed2json/convert?url=....

Any JS or PhP library to convert the Medium feed to json?

Comment: I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser for parsing