# How to convert rss to json for medium posts

Tags: json, rss, medium.com-publishing-api

I am trying to feed my website with my medium posts but I am not able to convert rss to json. So for this, like medium says I am trying to make this call [https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/${username}](https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/$%7Busername%7D) but when I make the call the response is like this:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Cannot download this RSS feed, make sure the Rss URL is correct."
}
```

So how can I do that? could you give me an example?

Comment: Check this answer, since your question is the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71912328/12031648

Comment: I am having the same problem but the answer didnt give me a solution

Comment: well i forwarded a solution to make it work, you're asking how to convert rss to json not specifically with api.rss2json.com. Everything is explained there, i don't know what you need more ?

Comment: I am trying to implement the medium posts to my website and basically I am following the same steps which are mentioned here: https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/embed-medium-as-a-blog-on-your-site-54a1b49cbe16 (Method 04: Custom Code
) but I am having problems converting rss to json and I am stucked there and the method you converted didnt help me much

Comment: `https://www.convertjson.com/cgi-bin/url-to-json.php?callback=loadDataAndRun&url=https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/` and it works fine for me

Comment: @DarioRega consider post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Either follow my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71912328/12031648) that details a bit what would be the best solution to overcome this, otherwise use this workaround:
`https://www.convertjson.com/cgi-bin/url-to-json.php?callback=loadDataAndRun&url=https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/`